# reduce singleton object in project

Tags: c++, singleton

Recently, I refactor code of my project, I found there are lots of singleton object, almost one function one singleton.

For example, I should do period task, so I have a class called CPeriodTask, and have a thread function called ScanPeriodTaskThreadProc and a member variable which save tasks, and CPeriodTask is a singleton object.

There are so many singleton object in my project, and a few of singleton object refer to
other singleton object.

Now I want to reduce use of singleton and break reference of singleton.
Any Suggestions, Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you have unit and acceptance tests that cover anything you are about to change. Digging these things out after the fact can get messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to reduce singletons is to create some god-class, a `SingletonManager`, which can then contain all of the other singletons as instance members.  That is, you remove the singleton behavior of the existing singletons in your projects, and this manager then creates/destroys these objects as desired, in the correct order, since you mentioned some of these objects have dependencies on each other.

So at the top of main, you create the SingletonManager, publish some reference to this object so the rest of your code can get at these former-singleton objects.  And, just as important, at the bottom of main, you "shutdown" the manager which itself then deterministically destroys these objects in the correct order.  Again, this is important because you mentioned inter-dependencies between these objects, and at least one singleton you have now involves a thread.

Answer (score 1):

Singleton is often overused. First have a look as to which Singletons are genuine in the sense that it woild only ever be possible to have one of them; these might be associated with devices, for example. A Singleton solves two problems: the number of instances and navigation to the object. I.e. They are really just globals. So to remove a global, you have to figure out what your new object model is going to be such as to allow navigation to the object. If you have a lot of singletons, you might find that keeping one of them as the root of an object hierarchy allows you to hang the rest of them from it. Thinking this way, ask why you now need more than one instance of various objects and whether they are always associated.

And: In future avoid Singletons/ globals except where truly merited.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is don't make them singletons. If they have the lifetime of the program, create them in main. If someone needs to do something with that object, then make it an explicit dependency.

Here's an example for you CPeriodTask

```
int main()
{
    // Create something so my program can use periodic tasks
    CPeriodTask* pMyPeriodicTasks = new CPeriodTask();

    // Object foo needs to do periodic tasks, lets pass this functionality in
    CFoo* myProgramsFoo = new CFoo(pMyPeriodicTasks);
}
```

Another option, expose a proxy to the shared resource and handle the resources behind the scenes:

```
class CMyPeriodicTask
{
public:
      // obtain resource
      CMyPeriodicTask(/*function ptr*/);

      // release resource
      ~CMyPeriodicTask();
};
```

Within this code, interface with whatever system code you need to start a periodic task. Then CFoo simply uses it:

```
class CFoo
{
private:
      CMyPeriodicTask periodicTask;
...
};
```

I'd suggest using the former case when not everyone needs the functionality and the latter case when the functionality will be heavily used.